How are numbers used here in this sentence?

「多数派ではありますが、決して総意ではありません。感覚として、六四で復権派の方が多い、というくらいでしょうか。しかも、復権派のほとんどは土御門系ですね」

The character asks "Is the hope for the restoration the consensus of the people?" to which the character replies this.
My reading of the sentence is "It is the majority, but it's not the consensus. My intuition is that the people hoping for the restoration are the majority, and what's more the faction hoping for the restoration is mostly made of 土御門系"
However, I'm not sure how 六四で here is used?

60% to 40%.
Proportions are often expressed in tenths, such as 3割引き (30% off), where a 割 means “tenth”.
七三分け is a hair style where the hair on top is divided at the 70% position.

Other examples: 十分 meaning "enough" or "plenty"; 五分 meaning "half" or "50% likelihood" etc.
